# plupload submit on queue complete

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, plupload

Using plupload jquery queue plugin as in [this example](http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php), how can I submit the form on upload complete? I attempted to add a `<input type="submit" />` button, and click this button without first clicking the `Start upload`. This triggers the `uploader.start()` correctly, and then `$('form').submit()` - however the $_POST data only contains: `'uploader_count' => string '0' (length=1)`. If I first click the `Start upload` button however, the proper POST vars are populated.

How can I trigger `.submit()` and be sure the correct file upload post parameters are present (E.G. `$_POST['uploader_count']`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in plupload, and is also present in the official example at:

http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php

(Queing files, then hit submit only sends POST data `$_POST['uploader_count'] == 0`) omitting any file info

Answer (score 0):

We added a button which does this:

```
    var plupload = form.find('.plupload-element'), uploader;
    event.preventDefault();
    if (plupload.length && plupload.pluploadQueue) {
      uploader = plupload.pluploadQueue();
      uploader.bind('StateChanged', function(uploader) {
        // Submit the form if all the files got uploaded.
        if (uploader.total && uploader.files && uploader.total.uploaded === uploader.files.length) {
          form.trigger('submit');
        }
```

Comment: That approach is currently giving me empty `$_POST['uploader_xx` values, as if no files where uploaded at all..